# Memory leak debug python

Tags: python, debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a python script that works fine on my main computer without problems. But when I uploaded it to the Ubuntu server it started crashing. I thought for a long time what the problem was and looked at the system logs. It turned out that ubuntu automatically forcibly terminates the script due to lack of memory (server configuration is 512 MB of RAM), how can I debug the program on the consumed memory in different work options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at something like [Guppy3](https://github.com/zhuyifei1999/guppy3), which includes `heapy`, a 'heap analysis toolset' that can help you find where the memory's being used/held.  Some links to information on how to use it are in the project's README.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a core, consider using https://github.com/vmware/chap, which will allow you to look at both python and native allocations.

Once you have opened the core, probably "summarize used" is a good place to start.